# WordPress: the database may need to be repaired

Tags: wordpress

I'm a beginner at WordPress, when I start running the project I encountered the problem of the database may need to be repaired.
I have been taken the troubleshooting steps but unfortunately, nothing has changed.
So, could someone here tell me which kind of problem occurred because I really couldn't get the solution?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems to be a newly introduced bug, see: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51676. Downgrade to WordPress 5.5.1 to get your website up and running and wait until that issue is resolved by the WP team.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have got the solution in the link you sent.it was a problem in line number 1756 of the file functions.php, there's a condition check if the tables in the database already exist. I changed it and it works correctly
Thanks for helping me <3 <3 <3

Comment: If possible, please add this as an answer and select it as the right answer.